# Doubly linked ring implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel

I was practicing C++ and data structures and wrote my own implementation of a doubly linked ring. I would love to improve my code a little bit more and would need help from the community.

Here is the implementation I have:

```
#ifndef BIRING_H_INCLUDED
#define BIRING_H_INCLUDED

#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

template<typename Key, typename Value>
class Ring
{

private:

    struct Element
    {
        Key key;
        Value value;
        Element* next;
        Element* prev;
    };

    Element* head;
    Element* tail;


public:
    class iterator
    {

    private:
        Element* ptr;

    public:

        iterator()
        {
            ptr=NULL;
        };

        iterator(const iterator & copy)
        {
            ptr=copy.ptr;
        };

        iterator(Element* copy)
        {
            ptr=copy;
        };

        ~iterator() {};



        iterator& operator=(iterator & copy)
        {
            ptr=copy.ptr;
        };

        iterator& operator=(Element* copy)
        {
            ptr=copy;
            return *this;
        };

        Key & operator*()
        {
            return ptr->key;
        };

        const Key & getKey()
        {
            return ptr->key;
        };

        const Value & getValue()
        {
            return ptr->value;
        };

        iterator operator+(const int i)const
        {
            iterator newthis = *this;
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
                newthis++;
            return newthis;
        };

        iterator& operator+=(const int i)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
                ptr=ptr->next;
            return *this;
        };

        iterator& operator++()
        {
            iterator a(*this);
            ptr=ptr->next;
            return a;
        };

        iterator operator++(int)
        {
            ptr=ptr->next;
            return *this;
        };

        iterator operator-(const int i)const
        {
            iterator newthis = *this;
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
                newthis--;
            return newthis;
        };

        iterator& operator-=(const int i)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
                ptr=ptr->prev;
            return *this;
        };

        iterator& operator--()
        {
            iterator a(*this);
            ptr=ptr->prev;
            return a;
        };

        iterator operator--(int)
        {
            ptr=ptr->prev;
            return *this;
        };

        bool operator==(const iterator & comp)const
        {
            return ptr==comp.ptr;
        };

        bool operator!=(const iterator & comp)const
        {
            return ptr!=comp.ptr;
        };

        bool isNull()const
        {
            return !ptr;
        };
    };


    Ring();
    ~Ring();

    Ring(const Ring<Key,Value> & copy);
    Ring<Key,Value> & operator=(const Ring<Key,Value> & copy);

    Ring<Key,Value> operator+(const Ring<Key,Value> & add)const;
    Ring<Key,Value> operator-(const Ring<Key,Value> & subtract)const;

    Ring<Key,Value>& operator++();
    Ring<Key,Value> operator++(int);

    Ring<Key,Value>& operator--();
    Ring<Key,Value> operator--(int);

    Ring<Key,Value> & operator+=(const Ring<Key,Value> & add)
    {
        *this=*this+add;
        return *this;
    };
    Ring<Key,Value> & operator-=(const Ring<Key,Value> & subtract)
    {
        *this=*this-subtract;
        return *this;
    };

    void clear();
    void reverse();


    iterator begin() const
    {
        return iterator(head);
    };


    iterator end() const
    {
        return iterator(tail);
    };

    unsigned int size() const;
    bool empty()const
    {
        return !head;
    };

    bool insertAt(unsigned int pos, const Key&key, const Value &value);
    bool insertAfter(const Key&keypos, const Key&key, const Value &value);
    bool insertAfter(const iterator & iter, const Key&key, const Value &value);

    void push_front(const Key&key, const Value &value);
    void push_back(const Key&key, const Value &value);
    void pop_front()
    {
        iterator a(begin());
        remove(a);
    };
    void pop_back()
    {
        iterator a(end());
        remove(a);
    };

    bool remove(const Key&key);
    bool remove(iterator & iter);
    bool removeAllOf(const Key&key);

    bool exists(const Key&key);

    bool operator==(const Ring<Key,Value> & check)const;
    bool operator!=(const Ring<Key,Value> & check)const;


    template<typename u, typename i>
    friend ostream & operator<< (ostream & os, const Ring<u,i> & toprint);


    iterator find(const Key &where) const;//move to the position of the designated ID
    iterator findPlace(int place) const;//move to the position of designated startindex
    bool findNodePlace(int place) const;

};



template <typename Key, typename Value>
unsigned int Ring<Key, Value>::size() const
{
    int length=0;
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        Element *current = head->next;
        length=1;
        while(current!=head)
        {
            length++;
            current=current->next;
        }
    }
    return length;
}


template<typename Key, typename Value>
Ring<Key,Value>::Ring()
{
    head=tail=NULL;
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
Ring<Key,Value>::Ring(const Ring<Key,Value> & copy)
{
    head=tail=NULL;
    Element * temp = copy.head;
    while (temp)
    {
        this->push_back(temp->key, temp->value);
        if(temp==copy.tail)
            break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
Ring<Key,Value>::~Ring()
{
    clear();
}


template<typename Key, typename Value>
Ring<Key,Value> & Ring<Key,Value>::operator=(const Ring<Key,Value> & copy)
{
    if(&copy==this)
        return *this;

    clear();

    Element * temp = copy.head;
    while (temp)
    {
        this->push_back(temp->key, temp->value);
        if(temp==copy.tail)
            break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    return *this;
}


template<typename Key, typename Value>
bool Ring<Key,Value>::operator==(const Ring<Key,Value> & check)const
{
    bool same = true;
    Element * temp1 = head;
    Element * temp2 = check.head;
    while(temp1&&temp2)
    {
        if(temp1->key!=temp2->key || temp1->value!=temp2->value)
            same = false;
        if(temp1==tail||temp2==check.tail)
            break;
        temp1=temp1->next;
        temp2=temp2->next;
    }
    return same;
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
bool Ring<Key,Value>::operator!=(const Ring<Key,Value> & check)const
{
    return !(*this==check);
};


template<typename Key, typename Value>
Ring<Key,Value> Ring<Key,Value>::operator+(const Ring<Key,Value> & added)const
{
    Ring<Key,Value> tempseq;
    Element * temp = head;
    while(temp)
    {
        tempseq.push_back(temp->key,temp->value);
        if(temp==tail)
            break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp = added.head;
    while(temp)
    {
        tempseq.push_back(temp->key,temp->value);
        if(temp==added.tail)
            break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return tempseq;
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
Ring<Key,Value> Ring<Key,Value>::operator-(const Ring<Key,Value> & subtract)const
{
    Ring<Key,Value> tempseq;
    Element * temp = head;
    while(temp)
    {
        tempseq.push_back(temp->key,temp->value);
        if(temp==tail)
            break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp = subtract.head;
    while(temp)
    {
        tempseq.removeAllOf(temp->key);
        if(temp==subtract.tail)
            break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return tempseq;
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
Ring<Key,Value>& Ring<Key,Value>::operator++()
{
    if(head)
    {
        head=head->next;
        tail=tail->next;
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
Ring<Key,Value> Ring<Key,Value>::operator++(int)
{
    Ring a(*this);
    if(head)
    {
        head=head->next;
        tail=tail->next;
    }
    return a;
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
Ring<Key,Value>& Ring<Key,Value>::operator--()
{
    if(head)
    {
        head=head->prev;
        tail=tail->prev;
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
Ring<Key,Value> Ring<Key,Value>::operator--(int)
{
    Ring a(*this);
    if(head)
    {
        head=head->prev;
        tail=tail->prev;
    }
    return a;
}


template<typename u, typename i>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Ring<u,i> & toprint)
{
    typename Ring<u,i>::Element* temp;
    temp = toprint.head;
    while(temp)
    {
        os << "Key: " << temp->key << endl << "Value: " << temp->value << endl;
        if(temp==toprint.tail)
            break;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return os;
}



template<typename Key,typename Value>
void Ring<Key,Value>::clear()
{
    Element * temp;
    temp=head;
    if(tail)
        tail->next=NULL;
    while(temp)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        delete head;
        head = temp;
    }
    head=tail=NULL;

}

template<typename Key,typename Value>
void Ring<Key,Value>::reverse()
{
    Ring<Key,Value> tempseq;
    Element * temp = head;
    while(temp)
    {
        tempseq.push_front(temp->key,temp->value);
        if(temp==tail)
            break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    *this=tempseq;
}

template<typename Key,typename Value>
bool Ring<Key,Value>::insertAt(unsigned int pos, const Key&key, const Value &value)
{
    if(pos>size())
        return false;

    Element * temp = head;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<pos; i++)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    Element * newElement;
    newElement = new Element;

    newElement->key=key;
    newElement->value=value;
    newElement->next=newElement;
    newElement->prev=newElement;

    if(!temp)
    {
        head=tail=newElement;
    }
    else
    {
        newElement->next=temp;
        newElement->prev=temp->prev;

        temp->prev->next=newElement;
        temp->prev=newElement;
    }

    if(pos==0){
        head=newElement;
   }else if(pos==size()){
        tail=newElement;
   }
    return true;
}

template<typename Key,typename Value>
bool Ring<Key,Value>::insertAfter(const Key&keypos, const Key&key, const Value &value)
{
    Element * temp = head;
    bool found = false;

    while(temp)
    {
        if(temp->key==keypos)
        {
            found=true;
            break;
        }
        if(temp==tail)
            break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    if(!found)
        return false;

    Element * newElement;
    newElement = new Element;
    newElement->key=key;
    newElement->value=value;

    newElement->next=temp->next;
    newElement->prev=temp;

    temp->next->prev=newElement;
    temp->next=newElement;

    if(head==tail){
        head=tail=newElement;
    }else if(temp==tail){
        tail=newElement;
    }
    return true;
}

template<typename Key,typename Value>
bool Ring<Key,Value>::insertAfter(const iterator & iter, const Key&key, const Value &value)
{
    Element * temp = head;
    bool found = false;
    iterator comp;

    while(temp)
    {
        comp=temp;
        if(comp==iter)
        {
            found=true;
            break;
        }
        if(temp==tail)
            break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    if(!found)
        return false;

    Element * newElement;
    newElement = new Element;
    newElement->key=key;
    newElement->value=value;

    newElement->next=temp->next;
    newElement->prev=temp;

    temp->next->prev=newElement;
    temp->next=newElement;

    if(head==tail)
        head=tail=newElement;
    else if(temp==tail)
        tail=newElement;

    return true;
}


template<typename Key, typename Value>
void Ring<Key,Value>::push_front(const Key&key, const Value &value)
{
    Element * newElement;

    newElement = new Element;
    newElement->key = key;
    newElement->value = value;

    if(head)
    {
        newElement->next = head;
        newElement->prev = tail;
        tail->next=newElement;
        head->prev=newElement;
        head=newElement;
    }
    else
    {
        newElement->next = newElement;
        newElement->prev = newElement;
        head=tail=newElement;
    }
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
void Ring<Key,Value>::push_back(const Key&key,  const Value &value)
{
    Element * newElement;

    newElement = new Element;
    newElement->key = key;
    newElement->value = value;

    if(head)
    {
        newElement->next = head;
        newElement->prev = tail;
        tail->next=newElement;
        head->prev=newElement;
        tail=newElement;
    }
    else
    {
        newElement->next = newElement;
        newElement->prev = newElement;
        head=tail=newElement;
    }
}


template<typename Key, typename Value>
bool Ring<Key,Value>::remove(const Key&key)
{
    Element* temp = head;
    while(temp)
    {
        if(temp->key==key)
        {
            if(head==tail)
            {
                delete temp;
                head = tail = NULL;
                size--;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                temp->next->prev=temp->prev;
                temp->prev->next=temp->next;
                size--;
                delete temp;
                return;
            }
        }
        if(temp==tail)
            break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
bool Ring<Key,Value>::remove(iterator& iter)
{
    if(iter.isNull())
        return false;
    Element* temp = head;
    iterator comp;
    while(temp)
    {
        comp = temp;
        if(comp==iter)
        {
            iter++;
            if(head==tail)
            {
                delete temp;
                head = tail = NULL;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                if(temp==head)
                    head=temp->next;
                else if(temp==tail)
                    tail=temp->prev;
                temp->next->prev=temp->prev;
                temp->prev->next=temp->next;
                delete temp;
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(temp==tail)
            break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
bool Ring<Key,Value>::removeAllOf(const Key&key)
{
    Element* temp = head;
    bool deleted = false;
    while(temp)
    {
        if(temp->key==key)
        {
            deleted=true;
            if(head==tail)
            {
                delete temp;
                head = tail = NULL;
                return deleted;
            }
            else
            {
                if(temp==head)
                    head=temp->next;
                else if(temp==tail)
                    tail=temp->prev;
                temp->next->prev=temp->prev;
                temp->prev->next=temp->next;
                delete temp;
            }
        }
        if(temp==tail)
            break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return deleted;
}




template<typename Key, typename Value>
bool Ring<Key,Value>::exists(const Key&key)
{
    Element * temp = head;
    while(temp)
    {
        if(temp->key==key)
            return true;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return false;
}


template<typename Key, typename Info>
typename Ring<Key, Info>::iterator Ring<Key, Info>::find(const Key &where) const
{
    iterator iter = begin();
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        do
        {
            if (iter.getKey() == where)
            {
                return iter;
            }
            iter++;
        }
        while (iter != begin());
    }
    return NULL;
}


template <typename Key, typename Info>
typename Ring<Key, Info>::iterator Ring<Key, Info>::findPlace(int place) const
{
    iterator iter = begin();
    int position = 0;
    if (head != NULL)
    {

        do
        {
            if (position == place)
            {
                return iter;
            }
            iter++;
            position++;
        }
        while (iter != begin());
    }
    return NULL;
}


template <typename Key, typename Info>
bool Ring<Key, Info>::findNodePlace(int place) const
{
    iterator iter = find(place);
    if (iter == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}


#endif // BIRING_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: ("Coming" from [CLASS SIMSET](http://simula67.at.ifi.uio.no/Standard-86/chap_11.htm), I'd love to see a contemporary take.) Can you please summarise, as an introduction to the longish code, a) interface (/envisioned usage) b) your goal in coding this? (I appreciate the hint in tagging *reinventing-the-wheel* - tell me more)

Comment: I just would like to learn from my mistakes and have a perfect implementation of the this

Answer (score 2):

Here are a number of things that may help you improve your program.  Since it's not specified, I'm going to assume C++17.

### Provide complete code to reviewers

This is not so much a change to the code as a change in how you present it to other people.  Without the full context of the code and an example of how to use it, it takes more effort for other people to understand your code.  This affects not only code reviews, but also maintenance of the code in the future, by you or by others.  One good way to address that is by the use of comments.  Another good technique is to include test code showing how your code is intended to be used.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  Know when to use it and when not to (as when writing include headers).

### Avoid spurious punctuation

The code currently has this function:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
bool Ring<Key,Value>::operator!=(const Ring<Key,Value> & check)const
{
    return !(*this==check);
};
```

That will compile and work, but the semicolon (`;`) at the end is not necessary and should be deleted.

### Make sure all paths return a value

The `remove` functions both claim to return a `bool`, but the version that takes a `const Key&` argument doesn't.  It should be a `void` function as written or better, make it work like the iterator version and actually return a `bool`.

### Don't return a pointer to a local object

The code for the iterator contains these member functions:

```
iterator& operator++()
{
    iterator a(*this);
    ptr=ptr->next;
    return a;
};

iterator operator++(int)
{
    ptr=ptr->next;
    return *this;
};
```

There are two problems with this.  First, they are swapped because the `operator++(int)` form is the one that should post-increment.  Second, and most importantly, the first function is returning a reference to a local object which will yield *undefined behavior* if anything tries to subsequently use it.

### Understand iterators

An iterator is required to be *dereferenceable*, so that if you are storing a collection of things in your data structure `ring` and write `auto item{ring.cbegin()};` it means that `item` should be an iterator that points to one of those things.  The problem here is that we're trying to store two things: a `Key` and a `Value`.  I would suggest that things could be made much simpler with something like this:

```
struct Item {
   Key key;
   Value value;
};

struct Element
{
    Item item;
    Element* next;
    Element* prev;
};
```

Now you can define the iterator dereference as returning an `Item`.

### Use `nullptr` rather than `NULL`

Modern C++ uses `nullptr` rather than `NULL`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr/1283623#1283623) for why and how it's useful.

### Remove spurious template declaration

The `Ring` class declaration currently includes this line near the end just above the declaration for `find`:

```
template<typename u, typename i>
```

I don't know why that is there, but it prevents the code from compiling and should be deleted.

### Fix `end()`

There is a problem with the iterator `end()` as currently written:

```
iterator end() const
{
    return iterator(tail);
};
```

The problem is that this returns an iterator to the last element, but what it should do is return an iterator that is [one past the last element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end).  That would be simple except that the doubly-linked list doesn't have an end the way it's currently written.  That leads to the next suggestion.

### Break the circularity

I'd suggest keeping the doubly-linked list, but inside the `Ring` don't actually connect the head and tail.  In other words, if `head` is defined, then `head->prev` should be `nullptr` and if `tail` is defined, then `tail->next` should be `nullptr`.  This not only helps with the iterator above, but also greatly simplifies the code for `push_front` and `push_back`:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
void Ring<Key,Value>::push_front(const Key&key, const Value &value)
{
    auto temp{new Element{{key, value}, nullptr, head}};
    if (head) {
        head->prev = temp;
        head = temp;
    } else {
        head = tail = temp;
    }
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
void Ring<Key,Value>::push_back(const Key& key,  const Value &value)
{
    auto temp{new Element{{key, value}, tail, nullptr}};
    if (tail) {
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    } else {
        head = tail = temp;
    }
}
```

If there is any purpose to traversing beyond the tail back to the head, that can be accomodated within the function needing it.

### Simplify your code

The `find` routine is more complex than it needs to be and other routines could use `find` to simplify.  Examples:

```
template<typename Key, typename Info>
typename Ring<Key, Info>::iterator Ring<Key, Info>::find(const Key &where) const
{
    for (iterator it{begin()}; it != end(); ++it) {
        if (it->key == where) {
            return it;
        }
    }
    return end();
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
bool Ring<Key,Value>::exists(const Key& key)
{
    return find(key) != end();
}
```

### Don't implement `ostream<<` for templated types

There is not a good reason to implement `ostream<<` for a templated type like this and many good reasons not to, including the fact that the user may want to define his or her own.

### Conform to standard template library norms

Instead of `size()` returning an `unsigned int`, it would be better to return a `std::size_t` to conform with the STL.